# how to use MSXML2 setTimeouts to prevent timeout error?

Tags: vbscript, timeout, msxml2

I use the following function to check if a URL responds in a few seconds:

```
function testUrl(url)
    Set xmlDOM = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
    xmlDOM.Open "GET", url, False
    xmlDOM.setTimeouts 1000,1000,1000,1000
    testUrl=xmlDOM.Send
end function

if testUrl("http://khabarfoori.com/rss/mm") then 
    responsw.write "active" 
    else 
    response.write "inactive"
end if
```

Instead of getting **"active"** or **"inactive"** I get the following error:

```
>     msxml6.dll error '80072ee2'
>     The operation timed out
```

**Footnote:** The tested URL above buffers a big amount of text with no server error. Is it a special case and I need more code to handle this kind of response?

Answer (score 0):

May be this can did the trick !

```
feed = "http://khabarfoori.com/rss/mm"
Set req = CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
req.Open "GET", feed, False
req.Send
Set xml = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
xml.loadXml(req.responseText)
First_Title = xml.getElementsByTagName("channel/item/title")(0).Text

If Len(First_Title) <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "active"
    MsgBox First_Title
else 
    MsgBox"inactive"
End If
```

Comment: This causes errors when the target url is not responding or has error